# Refresh page when user come back from another page, Navigate using Drawer menu

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have 2 pages: Page1() and Page2() and a Drawer menu.

To go Page2() I use (inside Drawer):

```
ListTile(
   title: Text("Go to Page 2"),
   onTap: () {
      Navigator.pop(context); // close Drawer
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Page2(),
      ));
   },
),
```

And when user is in Page2() and pressed back button (android devices). I want to come back Page1() and refresh it. I dont know how to do that.

I found this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => new Page2()))
        .then((val) => _refreshDataInPage1());
```

But only works when I use in a function inside Page1(). I can't understand how implement that in Drawer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `Navigator.pop` works in your case?

Comment: yes, it works. I use to close Drawer menu when user select go to Page2()

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Navigator.pop(context)`

[Navigator Class Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)